# Error installing mysql-connector-python on Amazon Linux AMI via pip-3.4

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-ec2, pip

Apologies in advance if this is an easy fix, I have searched for an answer with no luck.

I'm trying to install the mysql-connector[-python] package on Amazon's Linux AMI. For my purposes, I want to use Python 3.4. I've installed Python 3.4 and pip-3.4 with yum and have successfully installed a few packages already:

```
    pip-3.4 list
```

gives

```
    numpy (1.11.1)
    pip (6.1.1)
    setuptools (25.1.4)
    virtualenv (15.0.2)
```

However, when I try:

```
    sudo pip-3.4 install mysql-connector-python
```

I get

```
    Collecting mysql-connector-python
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysql-connector-python (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for mysql-connector-python
```

`sudo pip-3.4 install mysql-connector-python --allow-external mysql-connector-python` gives the same error. A google search suggested I use `sudo pip-3.4 install mysql-connector-python-rf --allow-external mysql-connector-python-rf` but then this gives the error:

```
    Collecting mysql-connector-python-rf
    Using cached mysql-connector-python-rf-2.1.3.tar.gz
    Installing collected packages: mysql-connector-python-rf
    Running setup.py install for mysql-connector-python-rf
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3.4 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-hotls6f7/mysql-connector-python-rf/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-wzpbgx5g-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: -c --help-commands
   or: -c cmd --help

error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3.4 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-hotls6f7/mysql-connector-python-rf/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-wzpbgx5g-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-hotls6f7/mysql-connector-python-rf
```

I've tried a number of things, such as

```
    echo https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.1.3.tar.gz >> requirements.txt
    sudo -H pip-3.4 install -r ./requirements.txt
```

which gives a similar error,

```
    sudo pip-3.4 install https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.1.3.tar.gz
```

which gives the same `error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized` error. I should also note that pip suggests I upgrade using `sudo pip-3.4 install --upgrade pip`, but when I do this pip breaks completely, even `pip-3.4 list` or `pip-3.4 --version` gives me `pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pip 8.1.2 (/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages), Requirement.parse('pip==6.1.1'))`.

I'm at a bit of loss as to what to do, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Answering my own question here, I know it doesn't solve the problem I had directly, but I've managed to get mysql-connector installed so that, in Python3(.4), `import mysql.connector` doesn't give any errors. Here's what I did:

```
    wget http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.0.4.zip#md5=3df394d89300db95163f17c843ef49df
    unzip mysql-connector-python-2.0.4.zip
    cd mysql-connector-python-2.0.4
    sudo python3 setup.py install
```

Now, in Python3:

```
    >>>import mysql.connector
    >>>
```

I'm still curious as to why I had previously gotten the error `error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized`. My guess is that it's an issue with `setuptools`, but I had upgraded it to the newest version (as well as `virtualenv`).

Comment: The current one is: http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.1.6.zip

Comment: For anyone, looking where to get the latest version, use the link:  https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/  and chose the "platform independent" version. Examples, of how to use the connector can be found at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html